Should I stop using EventEmitter?
My extension uses VS Code's EventEmitter for communication between components.
However I recently ran into a GitHub issue titled "Stop using EventEmitter"
To add to that - I could not find EventEmitter definition in the repository source code, and I can't find a way to use the new "Emitter" referenced on the GitHub issue.
So I am confused whether I should continue to use EventEmitter or not.

That looks like an internal communication to the vscode team to stop using EventEmitter in the source, not meant for extension developers.  The published api only has EventEmitter so I think you have no other choice.
